# What does a GPU kernel overhead consist of?

Tags: kernel, opencl, gpu, performancecounter

I have a piece of code that launches thousands of kernels and I am making a run-time performance model that explains the runtime based on the problem and machine specs.
What I need to know is, how can I relate the kernel overhead, to host and device performance specs(bandwidth, ...) , what parameters affect kernel overhead, and what is happening under the hood that causes the kernel overhead. I am using OpenCL

Comment: Are you asking about the reasons and parameters related to kernel launch itself? or do you also want information about the architectural parameters that influence the runtime of the kernels?

Comment: I am trying to make a performance model, and I don't know how to explain the kernel overhead in terms of the machine parameters